# Showing whether or not $\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,2)$

Tags: real-analysis

So I'm having trouble rigorously showing that $\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,2)$. So if we were to choose $\varepsilon=1$ and make $x<\delta$ then as $x$ gets closer to $0$, the $\delta$-neighborhood $N(x;\delta$) would need to shrink so much so that $x>\delta$. I just don't really know how to explicitly state this formally.

Comment: You *cannot* choose $\varepsilon=0$. The number $\varepsilon$ must be greater than $0$.

Comment: sorry that was a typo I meant $\epsilon$=1

Comment: If it is uniform continuous, than f is bounded by $|f(x_0)|+1$ in $(0, \delta)$ for any $x_0$ in that interval.